# Why wont my reverse LinkedList method not work more than once?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following method:

```
    public static IntNode reverse (IntNode head) {
            IntNode prev = null;
            IntNode curr = head;
            IntNode next = null;
            while(curr!=null) {
                next = curr.link;
                curr.link = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = next;
            }
            return prev;
        }
```

This works perfectly but when run twice it just returns the first (technically last) node in the linked list and nothing more, why is this the case and could you help me fix this? Thanks.

For Example :
Before reverse:
10
25
5
14
2
After reversal:
2
14
5
25
10
After typing reversal again:
10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method is correct.Just make sure whenever you call the reverse() method, assign the result of reverse() method to its head.

```
head = reverse(head);//correct coz head changes after reversal
```

when you fail to assign the result of reverse() method to head.

```
reverse(head)//Wrong coz head won't change after reversal
```

the head will not be updated and it will point to tail of linked list only.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire list is starts off with head. Once you switch your nodes around, head is now pointing to the last node (i.e. its .link is null).

You need to reset head as the first node in order for you to access the list.

Comment: How would the best way to do this be?

Comment: If your reverse method has direct access to head, then after the while loop set `head = prev`. Or, I see you are returning prev, if the place that calls the reverse method has access to head, then you can set it there.

Comment: I am using a second class to call this method since it is static and it looks like this: System.out.println(IntNode.reverse(head)), where the head here is an int node I created with: IntNode head = new IntNode(); that uses my no argument constructor in the IntNode class. I have no idea how to set head = prev in this case.

Comment: I'm not following, what class is the reverse method in? What class is head saved in? What class is calling the reverse method?

Comment: The reverse method is in IntNode class, where the method calling it is in IntNodeTest. The parameter head is used in the method, but the IntNode named head is used in IntNodeTest.

Comment: And when you are calling IntNode.reverse(), do you send it the direct access to head?

Comment: Yes, my command is: "IntNode.reverse(head)", with head being the IntNode object I created with "IntNode head = new IntNode();", both contained in the IntNodeTest class.

Comment: So then you should be able to change head by having it equal the now first node, (which should be prev at the end of the while loop). So try adding in `head = prev` right before you return and let me know what happens.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DAgeZu5.png, https://i.imgur.com/wYe2NtS.png both yield the same result

Comment: Hmm..then I'm not sure...hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out the issue. The variable head is not passed by true reference, meaning reassigning the address of this head doesn't reassign the address of the actual head. (you can only edit what is stored inside.) That is why you have to do it like sachin said.